# How do I attach a GPS receiver?

Tags: hardware, gps

I would like to hookup a GPS receiver to my Pi so that I can:

1. Get my geographical position
2. Synchronise clock when not connected to network

What are my options? Will any hardware supported by gpsd work with the Pi?

Comment: This sounds awesome!

Comment: This [GPS reciever](http://www.coolcomponents.co.uk/catalog/em408-module-p-44.html) looks like a good option, but I would have to have a play with it to provide a decent answer. It runs at 3V3 and 75mA, which is a good start!

Comment: Just wrote an answer about gpsd as I didn't notice it in the question. D'oh! FYI, here is the gpsd site: http://www.catb.org/gpsd/index.html which will give info on getting the time and location info from a software side.

Comment: You could also use a Bluetooth GPS device, so you can put it at the best position (e.g. near a window), although it needs a separate power supply. GPS devices speaking NMEA 0183 work with gpsd and they are pretty standard, so maybe you can find a used one. Bluetooth on the RPi should also work with most Bluetooth dongles.

Comment: My bounty will be awarded to an answer which provides a hardware schematic and software examples to set the clock and display geographical position.

Comment: I'd be interested in a GPIO/low level answer as well, anyone keen? I don't have a GPS module, otherwise I'd give it a shot using a serial/I2C connection

Comment: @AlexChamberlain The pi can only provide 50mA on the 3V3 pin. You would need to regulate the 5V down to 3V3 and use that to power the receiver.

Comment: @teraquendya Interesting! Source? Or is it obvious if I look at the schematic again?

Comment: I got it from the [elinux page here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals)

Comment: I have a Q&A that describes installing a generally-available G-Mouse USB GPS unit and software: 
 https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### GPS Receiver

I would go for a generic usb GPS receiver such as the [BU-353](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000PKX2KA)

[image: BU-353]

It works with the Raspberry Pi, just like a normal linux computer.

Most usb GPS receivers are just USB-to-Serial adapters that read the NMEA data from the GPS receiver. Look into pl2303 (many units i've seen use this particular chip) drivers, should be available.

You can also use GPIO and a traditional NMEA 0183 GPS receiver, but then you need to worry about power, and the prices are often higher. GPS antannas are common onboard boats and ships, and usually consume 12v.

The usb solution is cheaper.

### Software

The gps receiver I mentioned is compatible with [gpsd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpsd).

```
sudo apt-get install gpsd gpsd-clients python-gps
```

This will install gpsd and related software. Check gps status with `cgps -s`.

### NTP Clock

To synchronize the clock with [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), you need to install ntp.

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

See this blog post: http://blog.retep.org/2012/06/18/getting-gps-to-work-on-a-raspberry-pi/. It covers ntp in detail.

Comment: That blog post is great.

Comment: I can confirm that the BU-353 works with a Pi

Comment: Does ntp get the time from the GPS module when not connected to the Internet?

Comment: this will eat up your one usb port....

Comment: eat up usb port ?
then buy yourself a self-powered USB Hub

Comment: What does the clock synchronization provide? What is the benefit of it?

Comment: @JohnDemetriou Depends on the use case. A precise clock can make the difference between correct and incorrect timestamps - if you aggregate from multiple sensors with their own clock, you could for example get wrong ordering of events, if the clocks are differing.

Comment: My approach is very similar to that tutorial, but with some variations to make it work.  I did not do NTP.  You might want to take a look:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68816/how-can-i-set-up-my-g-mouse-usb-gps-for-use-with-raspbian

Answer (score 7):

Useful GPS Module for Raspberry Pi [Tutorial](http://www.cooking-hacks.com/index.php/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-gps)!

Comment: I'd like to see this sort of tutorial replicate here ... blogs are always disappearing ....

Comment: Downvoted due to the answer being link only

Answer (score 5):

[Look at adafruit ultimate gps](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/08/28/adafruit-ultimate-gps-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

> It’s got everything you want and more:
>
> -165 dBm sensitivity, 10 Hz updates, 66 channels
> 5V friendly design and only 20mA current draw
> Breadboard friendly + two mounting holes
> RTC battery-compatible
> Built-in datalogging PPS output on fix
> >25Km altitude
> Internal patch antenna + u.FL connector for external active antenna
> Fix status LED
>
> …all for under $40!

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to use USB you can use **TTL** GPS recievers. [Sparkfun does a very fast 50 channel GPS receiver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11571) but you can find other ones on eBay or other sites.

You can use this by [disabling the serial console on the P](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/5155/894)i and connect the receiver directly to the UART pins.

[image]

<sup>* Remember to check the voltages of the GPS device you are using</sup>

Comment: If you don't want to step the voltages down (as these modules are almost always 5v logic) you can plug them into a ttl to usb adapter, and the usb side into the Pi. This saves the serial console (for us who love it) and circumvents a voltage divider or level converter.