# what is the best video camera and gps to connect with raspberry pi

Tags: peripherals, video

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I attach a GPS receiver?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/547/how-do-i-attach-a-gps-receiver)

I am looking to start a project which will map an area capturing video on gps position with raspberry pi. I am looking for small camera and very precise gps to connect to raspberry.
Do you have an experience with connecting those devices and problems what I can run into.
Can you advise me some any particular product?

I would like to use it on moving platform and write the code in python.

Comment: Even though it is an interesting question, defined by the [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq) it is off topic. You are almost asking 3 question in one.. and asking us how to make something for you- The answers will be varied. Please ask specific questions. Like is Camera Model XYZ compatible with Pi. END; Or How can I wire this GPS Mode ABC to the GPIO, END; Please press the any key to continue...

Comment: You can also try and search this site and find [this](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/547/how-do-i-attach-a-gps-receiver) or the rest of the interwebs...

Comment: @ppumkin This is a grey area in relation to the FAQ as we allow some questions regarding the use and recommendation of peripherals. After all, peripheral usage is a big selling point of the Pi and there are many that it would be unwise to purchase.

Comment: Yes I know. But just by skimming this amazing Q&A i found great answers on how to use GPS. This question is pants and is frowned upon throughout stack exchange. He is not asking anything specific; All this data he is asking about can be found by searching the internet(sure it will take hours- that is his problem not ours) and learn him self. then come back and ask a specific question. Just saying...  -1 for laziness

Comment: @ppumkin Very well. It is gone. I have marked it as a dup of the other very popular GPS question, as that pretty much covers all these points.