# GPS module interfacing with a raspberry pi

Tags: gps

does anyone know details about connecting a GPS module to raspberry pi, i don't want to waste one USB port by using, GPSmodules with USB connection....

Comment: Waste ???? You could always use Self-powered USB Hub and expand USB ports. USB GPS module is indeed the best choice.

Comment: I moved my answer to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/547/how-do-i-attach-a-gps-receiver/10268#10268 as it is better suited there. Since this question will most likely be closed, removed, shredded and forgot about.

Comment: It's unclear how what you're asking is different from [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/547/20).  If you'd like to reopen the question, please edit it to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: A suggestion--if you're asking if there's a way to use a GPS module not hooked up through a USB port, change the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You should buy a GPS module that have serial (UART) interface. Then you can connect the GPS module to Raspberry Pi through GPIO pins. There is a blog about 3DR GPS module at http://diydrones.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-connect-3dr-gps-ublox-to-raspberry-pi

Comment: -1 The answer is in the link I provided in the comment. You should have voted to close this answer as its duplicate