# Connecting GPS Breakout to Pi

Tags: hardware, gps, cable

Good day
While looking for the smallest possible GPS solution for a Raspberry PI 2 searching has brought me to these solutions.

- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13670
- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11818

I am thinking of getting those two, but being more of a programmer than an hardware person I was thinking I would need some help connecting them to my Pi.

In this Post [How do I attach a GPS receiver?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/547/how-do-i-attach-a-gps-receiver). @ppumpkin mentioned that this can be connected to the Pi using the UART pins. ( I have male to female breadboard wire so I can do that)

However in the Datasheet for this device. The 6 pins are described as this

```
1 GND Ground, 2 VCC V Power Supply, 3 DP USB Positive, 4 DM USB Negative ,5 V_Bat Backup power,6 PWR_CTRL
```

So apart from pin 1 GND of the GPS being connected to the Pi's ground.
I'm not exactly sure where the remaining 5 Pins should be connected.

P.S will the Lat/Lon be returned in such a way where I can save it to a variable and pass it to a URL or whatever I decide I want to do with it?

Thank for any assistance or any resource which can help me.

Comment: always take a look at datasheets =) The answer is [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/GPS/GP-735T-150203.pdf) just one click off your link =)

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin I did look at the data sheet, Like i said... apart from the ground, i couldnt figure out what plugged into where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SparkFun site says

> Note: We are carrying the “T” option of this module which is TTL-UART
>   and not USB.

That is connected as follows.

```
GPS                 Pi
UART                Pin
TTL
1 Ground     ---    6 Ground
2 VCC (3.3V) ---    1 3V3
3 TXA        ---   10 RXD
4 RXA        ---    8 TXD
5 V_BAT      ---    No connection
6 PWR_CTRL   ---    No connection
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However I'm looking at it and would like some clarification, should pin 3 (TXA) on the UART go to pin 10 (RXD) and pin 4 (RXA) go to pin 8 (TXD).

Comment: Yes, it's usual for serial links to connect one ends TX to the other ends RX and vice versa.  The datasheet says "3 TXA Port A serial data output (from GPS) Output" which must be connected to the Pi's RXD pin.